# how to zoom map like fb image?

Tags: android, facebook, google-maps, animation

i show this link to zoom image http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

i want to try on my Map Fragment :When I click on hide map Map Should be maximize and on second click minimize map again with animation like http://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom.html

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
private LinearLayout layout;
private LinearLayout layoutmap;
private TextView search_txt_hide_map;
boolean hide = false;
private Animator mCurrentAnimator;

private int mShortAnimationDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_lin_search_list);
    layoutmap = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.search_lin_map);
    search_txt_hide_map = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.search_txt_hide_map);

    search_txt_hide_map.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (hide) {
                hide = false;
                zoomImageFromThumb();

            } else {
                hide = true;
                zoomImageFromThumb();

            }

        }
    });

     }

 private void zoomImageFromThumb() {

    if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
        mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
    }

    final LinearLayout expandedImageView =layoutmap;
    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    final Rect startBounds = new Rect();
    final Rect finalBounds = new Rect();
    final Point globalOffset = new Point();

    findViewById(R.id.container).getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBounds, globalOffset);
    startBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);
    finalBounds.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y);

    float startScale;
    if ((float) finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height()
            > (float) startBounds.width() / startBounds.height()) {
        startScale = (float) startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height();
        float startWidth = startScale * finalBounds.width();
        float deltaWidth = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2;
        startBounds.left -= deltaWidth;
        startBounds.right += deltaWidth;
    } else {
        startScale = (float) startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width();
        float startHeight = startScale * finalBounds.height();
        float deltaHeight = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2;
        startBounds.top -= deltaHeight;
        startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight;
    }

    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    expandedImageView.setPivotX(0f);
    expandedImageView.setPivotY(0f);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set
            .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left,
                    finalBounds.left))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top,
                    finalBounds.top))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
            .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f));
    set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
    set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            mCurrentAnimator = null;
        }
    });
    set.start();
    mCurrentAnimator = set;

    final float startScaleFinal = startScale;
    expandedImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mCurrentAnimator != null) {
                mCurrentAnimator.cancel();
            }

            AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
            set
                    .play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScaleFinal))
                    .with(ObjectAnimator
                            .ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScaleFinal));
            set.setDuration(mShortAnimationDuration);
            set.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            set.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                    expandedImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mCurrentAnimator = null;
                }
            });
            set.start();
            mCurrentAnimator = set;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

this is my xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<!-- <include layout="@layout/menu" /> -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/app"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/search_lin_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/search_txt_hide_map"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="hidemap"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/search_lin_action"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_lin_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/search_mapView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_lin_search_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```